# Convenient way to add inline formatting to usage Messages

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

Usage `Messages` of built-in functions have embedded in-line formatting. For example:

```
In[1]:= ActionMenu::usage // FullForm

Out[1]//FullForm= 
"\!\(\*RowBox[{\"ActionMenu\", \"[\", RowBox[{StyleBox[\"name\", \"TI\
\"], \",\", RowBox[{\"{\", \
RowBox[{RowBox[{SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"lbl\", \"TI\"], \
StyleBox[\"1\", \"TR\"]], \":>\", SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"act\", \"TI\
\"], StyleBox[\"1\", \"TR\"]]}], \",\", \
RowBox[{SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"lbl\", \"TI\"], StyleBox[\"2\", \
\"TR\"]], \":>\", SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"act\", \"TI\"], \
StyleBox[\"2\", \"TR\"]]}], \",\", StyleBox[\"\[Ellipsis]\", \
\"TR\"]}], \"}\"}]}], \"]\"}]\) represents an action menu with label \
\!\(\*StyleBox[\"name\", \"TI\"]\), and with items labeled \
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"lbl\", \"TI\"], StyleBox[\"i\", \
\"TI\"]]\), that evaluates the expression \
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"act\", \"TI\"], StyleBox[\"i\", \
\"TI\"]]\) if the corresponding item is chosen."
```

One can see that this in-line formatting is based on the set of styles defined in "Styles for Inline Formatting" section of the Core.nb stylesheet. But I have not found any documentation for these styles as well as any description of the convenient algorithm of adding formatting to `usage` `Message`s.

What is the convenient way to add in-line formatting to user-defined `usage` `Message`s in *Mathematica*? What are the usage rules of default styles for in-line formatting defined in the Core.nb stylesheet? I would like to add in-line formatting to the `usage` `Message`s in my package just with *Mathematica*, without installing additional components like Workbench etc.

P.S. The syntax of the embedded in-line formatting in `String`s is partially documented on the tutorial page "[String Representation of Boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html)." Related question in the official newsgroup on this syntax: "[(any documentation for) linear syntax?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/xp4fuxv_ODk/tOqGkuy3RWgJ)" Displaying of such strings in the FrontEnd is controlled by the option `ShowStringCharacters->False` of `Cell`.

Comment: Related http://www.mathematicahelp.info/minor-progress-with-6-0-documentation

Comment: I am not posting this as an answer because you explicitly disregarded the WorkBench. But I think you are after something like this palette http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/reference/DocumentationTools/tutorial/AuthoringSymbolPagesUsingDocumentationTools.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems of handling strings like that is that most operations with strings in Mathematica automatically replace the backslash (`\`) with the escaped backslash (`\\`).

If you try this:

[image]

you may think you have the string you're looking for (minus the `\!` to make it an expression), but in fact it is: `"\\(x\\_\\(1, 2\\) \[Equal] \\(\\(-b\\) \[PlusMinus] \\@\\(b\\^2 -\\(4\\ a\\ c\\)\\)\\)\\/\\(2\\ a\\)\\)"`

My solution  is far from elegant, but it works.

1. Generate boxes from your formatted  expression:
   [image]
2. Select the output, and go to menu item `Cell > Convert to > InputForm`. Result:
   [image]
3. You can now edit the string, putting `\!` in front of it and  quotes around it:
   `"\!\(x \_ \(1, 2\) == \(\(-b\) \[PlusMinus] \@\(b \^2 - \(4\ a\ c\)\)\) \/ \(2\ a\)\)"`

If you perform step 3 in an external editor, leave away the quotes and just have `\!` in front and paste back the result in MMA it is directly converted to the formatted expression

Comment: +1. I was unaware that `InputForm` of boxes is linear form. See my answer for additional observations.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to just use the Front End to format your string.
If you are writing a package, you can use "auto-save packages" (i.e. when the contents of the initialization cells of a notebook become the package).
If you use a text editor to write the package then it might just be too much trouble to use formatting ...

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an addition to Sjoerd's answer.

First of all, we do not have to use the FrontEnd command `Cell > Convert to > InputForm` to get the linear form of boxes. We can get it just by applying `InputForm` to the output of `MakeBoxes`:

```
In[1]:= InputForm@MakeBoxes[Subscript[x, 1,2]==(-b\[PlusMinus]Sqrt[b^2-4 a c])/(2 a)]
Out[1]//InputForm=
\(x\_\(1, 2\) == \(\(-b\) \[PlusMinus] \@\(b\^2 - \(4\ a\ c\)\)\)\/\(2\ a\)\)
```

Secondly, we can export the final typesetting in-line string representation of boxes by the following two ways with equivalent result (the only difference is that `Put` wraps the text):

```
OutputForm@
  StringInsert[
   ToString[
    InputForm@
     MakeBoxes[
      Subscript[x, 1, 2] == (-b \[PlusMinus] Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(
       2 a)], OutputForm], "\\!", 1] >> "C:\\input.txt"

Export["C:\\input.txt", 
 StringInsert[
  ToString[InputForm@
    MakeBoxes[
     Subscript[x, 1, 2] == (-b \[PlusMinus] Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)],
    OutputForm], "\\!", 1], "String"]
```

In both cases we get a file with one line: `\!\(x\_\(1, 2\) == \(\(-b\) ± \@\(b\^2 - \(4\ a\ c\)\)\)\/\(2\ a\)\)`.

Inserting this line in a Notebook in the FrontEnd gives the original expression (try it by yourself!):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: would you happen to know how to quickly format a letter using Times New Roman Italic ("TI")? What I do is type the letter then go to fonts and switch it. But when I look at the full form I get something like `StyleBox[\"L\",FontFamily->\"Times\",FontSize->11,FontWeight->\"Plain\",FontSlant->\"Italic\"]` instead of the shorted version `StyleBox[\"L\", \"TI\"]`. I've also been having problems with this when I try to create an index as it is described [here](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/m_documentation/m_documentation.html).

Comment: @jmlopez Select your text, then press Alt+0 and enter `"TI"` in the dialog box. Alternatively, use `Format > Style > Other...` menu item.

Comment: thanks, this simplifies the formatting process. Going back to your original example: `ActionMenu::usage`. If you look at `?ActionMenu` on a notebook you will see a formatted message. Now, if you look for `ActionMenu start:1` in the doc center you will see the same message without the italic times new roman. Is this not the same `ActionMenu::usage` message? I've been trying to build my index by setting the summary of a function to `functionName::usage` but I always end up with `StyleBoxes` all of the place. Is there a way to remove the formatting from `ActionMenu::usage`?

Comment: @jmlopez Yes, what you see in the Documentation Center is of course completely independent on the `::usage` messages. As I understand, the contents of the page `ActionMenu start:1` is generated on the fly by some Java code which removes formatting. It seemingly has some special rules on converting two-dimensional elements like `SubscriptBox` to one-dimensional form. I do not know how to do this in *Mathematica*. Probably it is worth to create separate question on it.

Comment: I don't know if you have checked my most recent [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574710/integrating-notebooks-to-mathematicas-documentation-center). If you find out how to do it please share it. :)